# Rails has_many :through with custom attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I currently have a model for a vehicle, which has a custom method for defining an owner attribute:

```
def owners
    @owners = sales.map(&:customer) + quotes.map(&:customer)
    @owners = @owners.uniq
end
```

This method seems to work just fine, and returns an array of owners for the vehicle.

I am having a problem, however, when I want to use the `owners` that this method generates in another model. When I do this on another model:

```
has_many :owners, :through => :vehicles
```

This generates the error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :owner or :owners in model Vehicle.
```

I have tried adding `:source => :owners` but I get the same error.

I should point out that I do have `:owners` in attr_accessible.

So, can I do a :through association when owners is defined in a custom method, rather than being a normal variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no.

Rails' `has_many :through` functionality is intended to work on ActiveRecord associations. Here, you're declaring an association to a table called `owners` through the `vehicles` table, but in actuality there is no owners table to join to: since you find the owners manually with an attribute, you aren't saving them as records in the database.

To get this working for you, I would just skip using ActiveRecord associations. Instead just define something like this on the model in question:

```
def owners
  self.vehicles.collect(&:owners).flatten.uniq
end
```

You *can* use a through association if you start saving owners in your database, though, in which case the syntax you've provided will work.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails Api says that the through: option expects you to specify an association through which to perform the query. It's trying to find this owners association based on the join table vehicles, but can't find it, since it's not there. I don't think your apporach can work without heavily diving into the HasMany-Builder from Rails.